# clang-omp++ with xcode - libiomp5.dylib

Tags: xcode, clang, openmp

In the office instruction [here](https://clang-omp.github.io/), it tells us to Add `/usr/local/lib/libiomp5.dylib` to *Link Binary With Libraries* under *Build Phases*. It is really confused. I tried to click on the **+** button on *Link Binary With Libraries* to *add new frameworks or library* but I can't find libiomp5.dylib anywhere. Any help please?

[image]

Comment: The pane lists only frameworks from locations known to XCode. Click on "Add Other..." and then navigate to `/usr/local/lib` and select the OpenMP runtime library file to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I couldn't add the "/usr/local/lib/libiomp5.dylib" path. Even when I click on the option "add others" as because this folder is a hidden folder (even I have activated to see the hidden files and folder in mac), this folder is not visible inside from Xcode panel.

So, what I did is to manually copy this particular file from the location (/usr/local/lib/libiomp5.dylib) to any other folder (which is not hidden one, remember try to drag-&-drop because cmd+c and cmd+v does not work as it creates the shortcut of the file) and now, you can link the file from "add others" option in Xcode.

See [this link](https://clang-omp.github.io/) for complete instruction (follow only this section "Using clang-omp with Xcode")

please remember to include header file in the code like this :

```
#include <libiomp/omp.h>
```